# Where can I find some amusing cartoons about software testing?

Tags: training

I came across this Dilbert cartoon this week that I thought was pretty funny.  What other good software testing related cartoons are out there?

[image]

Comment: Torn between off-topic and NaRQ, but either way... This isn't helpful.

Comment: Please edit this with the duplicate revisions.  I think this is very helpful when framed as communicating the role of the tester using humor.  I know I could use good comics to post in my cubicle to reduce dev / test tension and help explain some of the more, ah, "challenging" tester behaviors.

Answer (score 4):

Here's one that has a short list (the site hasn't been around long). http://www.softwarequalityconnection.com/cartoon-archive/

You can also find a pretty good list here:

http://www.softwaretestpro.com/List/Cartoons

And that actually has several links to

http://cartoontester.blogspot.com/

I've made this a community wiki so that others can add to the list.

Comment: +1 for making it a community wiki. Great idea. A community wiki is a good way to go for a highly subjective question like this that (A) is more about trying to find multiple pretty good sources as opposed to finding "the one best answer" and (B) where good answers don't require a lot of explanation / detailed reasoning.