# Where can I find some insightful cartoons and/or humorous content about software testing?

Tags: training

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I find some amusing cartoons about software testing?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/712/where-can-i-find-some-amusing-cartoons-about-software-testing)

As Leo Rosten eloquently stated, "Humor is the affectionate communication of insight."

Here is one such example that pertains to software testing:

[image]

I am looking for cartoons or other funny examples that convey insight about common software testing challenges for potential inclusion in software testing seminars and/or management presentations.

Introducing potentially divisive issues through the use of humor can be an effective first step towards change management initiatives, for example.

What other insightful software-testing sources of comics or other humorous content would you recommend I explore?

Note: Obviously, this is a subjective question. Please see the [meta.sqa discussion](https://sqa.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72/should-this-site-officially-welcome-subjective-questions) about recommended guidelines concerning the appropriateness of asking subjective questions.

Comment: Trying this again. :-)

Comment: I have to agree with Shog's closing of the first post. At first I thought it was great. Then I re-read the guidelines, and I don't feel it's appropriate. This fails the "why versus how" test, the "long not short answer" test, the "opinion backed by fact" test, and in my opinion, also the "more than mindless social fun" test.

Comment: Furthermore, reposting a closed topic is generally taboo. If you feel it was closed incorrectly, the proper thing to do would be to edit the question to rephrase, vote to re-open (if you can) and/or flag for moderator attention to indicate that you feel it no longer is a close-worthy question.

Comment: Thanks for your views.  To clarify, I actually did edit it a great deal to establish the case for why it is a "real" question vs. one that could be construed as "mindless social fun".  I wasn't aware of the vote to re-open options or flag for moderator attention options.

Comment: Also, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/528311/is-there-a-cartoon-guide-to-oop as a precedent of a similar question that has been open on stackoverflow for several years.  Like this one, it asks, "Is there cartoon-based content (related directly to the subject matter of the community) that is suitable to helping me advance my professional objectives?"

Comment: I challenge the notion that this is subjective. Do such cartoons exist? They do. There are links to them. One can not say "well, its a matter of opinion whether or not there are QA-related cartoons on one link or another". It may be off-topic, but it is by no means subjective.

Comment: @Justin I respect your difference of opinion on the matter. I still feel it's inappropriate (although secretly I'm hoping there's answers just because I enjoy funny things...) In regard to the precedent, there are many questions on StackOverflow (especially from its early history, which that question is) that have been overlooked by the moderating staff which was much smaller at the time of that posting. The 'rules of the road' for StackOverflow have also evolved since then. I would also say that while there are parallels, the rules of SQA are defined by SQA and its users, not StackOverflow.

Comment: @Justin: you can edit your original post if you think you can turn this into something more than fluff. If you want a discussion regarding its appropriateness, [post on Meta.](http://meta.sqa.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 4):

Here's one that has a short list (the site hasn't been around long). http://www.softwarequalityconnection.com/cartoon-archive/

You can also find a pretty good list here:

http://www.softwaretestpro.com/List/Cartoons

And that actually has several links to

http://cartoontester.blogspot.com/

I've made this a community wiki so that others can add to the list.